# Quartz Manual Job run not picking up Trigger data

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job with multiple triggers each scheduled to run at different times. Each trigger also has its `<job-data-map></job-data-map>`. When I run the job manually - `scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, groupName)` - Quartz does not pick up the job data associated with each trigger. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are answering yourself. You have a job without job data and a set of triggers associated with that job.

When you are running the job manually using:

```
scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, groupName)
```

it basically creates some temporary trigger on the fly and runs the job immediately. Obviously there is no job data associated with that trigger. After all, if each trigger has a different job data, which one should be used when no trigger is specified?

Why not use the [`triggerJob(JobKey, JobDataMap)`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#triggerJob%28org.quartz.JobKey,%20org.quartz.JobDataMap%29) method that allows you to pass arbitrary job data?

Comment: Is there a way to specify a pre-defined trigger that's specified in your quartz.xml file while executing a job manually?

Comment: @user1689757: instead of calling `triggerJob()` you can `scheduleJob()` with trigger pointing to *now*. Will have the same effect.